# PNG pictures lose quality when saved in camera roll

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, image

In my app, I draw PNG picture and I want to save it in camera roll in order to share that picture with other apps. But, the saved pictures lose quality. There is a sample below to show  the problem.
- Left: Picture saved in system/memory (good quality).
- Middle: Picture saved in camera roll and sent to twitter.
- Right: Picture saved in camera roll and sent by gmail. Besides lost quality, extension changed to jpg.

[image: artifacts]

And my code,

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

//The sample of draw
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageView.frame.size, YES, 0.0f);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 1.0f);
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor redColor].CGColor);
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor);
CGContextAddRect(context, imageView.frame);
CGContextFillPath(context);
CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 40, 40);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 40, 120);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 120, 40);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 40, 40);
CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 200, 120);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 200, 200);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 120, 200);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 200, 120);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 120, 40);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 120, 200);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 40, 120);
CGContextStrokePath(context);

imageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

//Saving in directory on iPhone
NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageView.image);
NSArray* documentDirectories = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask,YES);
NSString* documentDirectory = [documentDirectories objectAtIndex:0];
NSString* documentDirectoryFilename = [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Sample.png"];
[data writeToFile:documentDirectoryFilename atomically:YES];
NSLog(@"documentDirectoryFileName: %@",documentDirectoryFilename);

//Save in camera roll
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum([UIImage imageWithData:data], nil, nil, nil);
}
```

So, I ask your help to avoid the loss quality or a better way to share pictures.

Comment: sorry but do you mean by "Picture saved in system/memory?" Are you taking this pic as a screen shot from device? (power and home button pressed at the same time?)

Comment: As showed in the code, I draw a picture using graphic context and same picture is saved in directory on iPhone and in camera roll, in order to compare the quality of these two saved pictures.

Comment: Have you checked byte size? Are the files identical in size i.e. one in photo album Vs appDoc dir? You code looks fine and I am surprised that  they change depending upon where you save. Try running this in simulator on your laptop and open them up in native photo editor app

Comment: Most likely the image is converted to a JPG when sent to the camera roll. JPG is terrible for line drawings.